# SQL - Find object with the highest count in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max

I am answering questions about an IMDB database as shown below.
[image: http://i.imgur.com/kj8qVgF.png]

I need to find which TV show (which is a kind_type that shows up as 'tv series') has the most episodes, actors and actresses, and seasons (these are separate parts of the question).
To start off, I wrote a query to find the name of the TV show that has the most actresses:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT t.title, count(t.title) total
FROM title t
INNER JOIN kind_type k
ON (t.kind_id = k.id)
INNER JOIN cast_info c
ON (c.movie_id = t.id)
CROSS JOIN role_type r
GROUP BY t.title
HAVING r.role = 'actress' AND k.kind = 'tv series'
ORDER BY total DESC
) as newTable
LIMIT 1
```

However, I get the error:

```
column "r.role" must appear in the GROUP 
BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 11: HAVING r.role = 'actress' AND k.kind = 'tv series'
```

So you can think of it as having a lot of cast_info objects, each attached to role_type objects. Each cast_info also has a variable for the movie_id, and I aimed to select a list of all cast_info objects that had role_types with the role 'actress', and then pick out the most frequently occurring 'movie_id' that shows up in that list.

Example:
[image: table]

In this example, the query should ideally return "3" because that is the movie ID that has the most actresses.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions about your assignments, at some point you'll need to answer them yourself

Comment: Shouldn't your "CROSS JOIN role_type r" by "INNER JOIN role_type r ON c.ID = r.ID"? The CROSS JOINing convolutes the logic enormously as now the role actress is associated with every rowset within title+kind_type+cast_info, and this is likely the cause of the error. I would expect changing the join will solve your problem, though I myself would put what you have in the HAVING clause in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple fix and likely just a mistake on your part.

You're receiving the error because you're putting a regular condition inside your HAVING clause. HAVING is used for conditions regarding aggregate functions.

For example, if you were trying to select only rows with a total greater than 2, you use having:

```
HAVING total > 2
```

However, what you want needs to go in a WHERE clause. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT t.title, count(t.title) total
   FROM title t
   INNER JOIN kind_type k
   ON (t.kind_id = k.id)
   INNER JOIN cast_info c
   ON (c.movie_id = t.id)
   JOIN role_type r
   ON (r.id = c.role_id)
   WHERE r.role = 'actress' AND k.kind = 'tv series'
   GROUP BY t.title
   ORDER BY total DESC
   ) as newTable
LIMIT 1
```

Here is more info on the [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. That was silly of me. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @joeBalin no problem, best of luck on this project.